# Cannot use table 'AspNetRoles' for entity type 'AspNetRoles' since it is being used for entity type 'IdentityRole'

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

The full error message:

**InvalidOperationException: Cannot use table 'AspNetRoles' for entity type 'AspNetRoles' since it is being used for entity type 'IdentityRole' and there is no relationship between their primary keys.**

Each time I am trying to access the database using **Entity FrameWork Core** to read/write data I am getting this exception.
The code generating the exception could be as simple as
`var p = _context.Platforms.Where(c=> c.PlatformId == 1);`
I am using **Identity** and my database context is inheriting from `IdentityDbContext<AspNetUsers>`

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2

Comment: Could you show your code pls?

Comment: Have you added proper database migrations?